# Multicasting over Ethernet on Android?

Tags: android, usb, multicast, ethernet, lan

My java app running on an Android 4.4 tablet receives pretty fine multicast packages over WLAN from a server. However, when I instead connect the tablet via an external USB ethernet LAN adapter to the network, no more multicast packages are received. The USB ethernet LAN adapter works fine with all TCP/UDP (unicast) packages, so what could be the reason? Are ethernet LAN adapters restricted to any special multicast IP group? 224.0.0.251 works fine over WLAN and I tried some other with no effect... Any idea would be welcome!